# LinkedIn share API - Allow users to share custom content and preview in popup similar to what facebook does with its SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, linkedin-api

I am trying to add a linkedin share button to my application that will allow users to share content. I want to override the page meta tags and add custom image and text in my sharable. I know the easiest way to share to linkedin is by opening http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle popup but this takes into account the page meta tags and there is no way to override. I tried using linkedin api and I am going through documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context. I have created a linkedin app and used the api key in my js. Is it possible using the linkedin api to do something similar to what facebook SDK does with FB.ui method (i.e share custom content using the share popup)?

Comment: Just FYI, Facebook does not really allow this any more either. (Using method `og:shares` is a workaround/loophole that is still open, but that might change at any time.)

Comment: But regarding your question, doesn’t https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-article-or-url-share answer it already?

Comment: @04FS I am able to do that in FB after creating a facebook app using FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        display: 'popup',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify(...) ...

Comment: As far as I understand linkedin requires user to authenticate first within my app in order to be able to share something. But I don't want that. I want user to click on a button, open linkedin sharer and show the sharable (which I want to be configurable based on which button user clicked)

Comment: As I said, what you are currently doing should be considered a workaround only - Facebook does not allow to specify these parameters dynamically at the time of share any more (reason mostly: fake news), _except_ when using this particular method … and that loophole could get closed at any time. The proper way to do this would be Open Graph meta tags (if you want to share multiple different “versions” of a piece of content, with different title, description or thumbnail, you should provide unique URLs for each), and that is what the recommended way to provide this data for LinkedIn is as well.